# Is it possible to have dropdownmenu in place of dropdownlist in asp.net? whenever user moves mouse over that control it should display items in it

Tags: asp.net, controls, drop-down-menu

i have dropdownlists in my asp.net web site, now i want to switch them into something like  `menu`  and its items should look like `menu items`, at `mouseover event items in that control should be displayed`, is it possible to achieve? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very well possible using javascript/jquery and setting the css to give it the placing and affects you feel like. You will many such examples googling it out....one such is: http://www.queness.com/post/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you like to convert an existin dropDownList to a menou like I know the the [**Linkselect**](http://www.givainc.com/labs/linkselect_jquery_plugin.htm) jQuery plug-in but also I know a similar from [Yahoo User Interface Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

jQuery or other library is strongly suggested for a complex conversion like that, at least the examples I know use a library.